# Set Umbraco Property Editor Input to jQueryUI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, datepicker, umbraco

I'm close but still can't quite get this to work.

I have a new custom property editor that is loading correctly and is doing almost everything expected until I try to set the text field to be a jQuery UI element.

As soon as I add a directive in Angular for setting it to call the jQuery UI datepicker function, I get the following error suggesting it hasn't loaded the jQueryUI script library correctly:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Trouble is, I can't see where I should be adding it as the logical places (to my mind, at least) seem to make no difference. Here is the code in full:

```
function MultipleDatePickerController($scope, assetsService) {

    //tell the assetsService to load the markdown.editor libs from the markdown editors
    //plugin folder
    //assetsService
    //    .load([
    //        "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"
    //    ])
    //    .then(function () {
    //        //this function will execute when all dependencies have loaded            
    //    });

    //load the seperat css for the editor to avoid it blocking our js loading
    assetsService.loadCss("/css/jquery-ui.custom.min.css");

    if (!$scope.model.value) {
        $scope.model.value = [];
    }

    //add any fields that there isn't values for
    //if ($scope.model.config.min > 0) {
    if ($scope.model.value.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.value.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) > $scope.model.value.length) {
                $scope.model.value.push({ value: "" });
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.add = function () {
        //if ($scope.model.config.max <= 0 || $scope.model.value.length < $scope.model.config.max) {
        if ($scope.model.value.length <= 52) {
            $scope.model.value.push({ value: "" });
        }
    };

    $scope.remove = function (index) {
        var remainder = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < $scope.model.value.length; x++) {
            if (x !== index) {
                remainder.push($scope.model.value[x]);
            }
        }
        $scope.model.value = remainder;
    };

}

var datePicker = angular.module("umbraco").controller("AcuIT.MultidateController", MultipleDatePickerController);

datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(function () {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. This is probably a bit of a hack, but it's simple and effective so it's a win nonetheless.

The assetsService call is the key, where I've put code into the deferred `.then` statement to call jQueryUI's datepicker on any item that has the "jqdp" CSS class:

```
//tell the assetsService to load the markdown.editor libs from the markdown editors
//plugin folder
assetsService
    .load([
        "/App_Plugins/Multidate/jquery-ui.min.js"
    ])
    .then(function () {
        //this function will execute when all dependencies have loaded    
        $('.jqdp').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
```

I've then gone and added that class to my view:

```
    <input type="text" jqdatepicker name="item_{{$index}}" ng-model="item.value" class="jqdp" id="dp-{{model.alias}}-{{$index}}" />
```

Finally, I've added a directive to ensure that dynamically-added items also display a datepicker:

```
datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {

    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch("jqdatepicker", function () {
            try{
                $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
            }
            catch(e)
            {}
        });
    };

});
```

As I said, this is possibly a bit hacky but it achieves the right result and seems like a simple solution.

Comment: The first part is I did it, but the $watch is new to me. So that "listens" for changes and fires them? Seems like a good solution!

Comment: Yeah, basically. The first part sets a datepicker control to any existing values in the property's array, while the $watch handles any newly-added values.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when adapting a [jQuery Date Range Picker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) for my [Date Range Picker](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/diplo-date-range-picker) package for Umbraco 7. It's frustrating! The problem (I think) is that Angular's `ng-model` listens for "input" changes to trigger events and so doesn't pick up on a jQuery triggered event.

The way around it I found was to force the input event of the element you wish to update to fire manually, using jQuery's [.trigger() event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

For example, the date picker I was using had this code for when a date was changed:

```
updateInputText: function () {
    if (this.element.is('input')) {
        this.element.val(this.startDate.format(this.format) + this.separator + this.endDate.format(this.format));
    }
},
```

I just adapted it to force an input trigger by adding `this.element.trigger('input')` to the code block, so it now reads:

```
updateInputText: function () {
    if (this.element.is('input')) {
        this.element.val(this.startDate.format(this.format) + this.separator + this.endDate.format(this.format));
        this.element.trigger('input');
    }
},
```

This forces Angular to "see" the change and then `ng-model` is updated. There may well be a more elegant way (as I'm an Angular newbie), but I know this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. At this stage I'm keen to see whether Angular will recognise the existing jQuery UI controls in the first instance, without falling back to other libraries. If it turns out that there's no better way then I'll definitely follow this up.